# Adafruit Ultimate GPS HAT Connections

Tags: uart, gps

I have been messing around with [this GPS HAT](https://www.adafruit.com/products/2324) for a few days now. I do have it working, although I have multiple modules running at once on stacked breadboards.

My main question is on AdaFruit's website, they claim the GPS's PPS module (when a fix is acquired) is on pin #4. When I look at the Raspi-Pi GPIO pinout, it shows this as 5VDC. How can this be, if it is transferring data serially?

EDIT: I have the Raspberry Pi Model B+ V1.2 if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe they are referring to the pin on the hat not the pin on the Pi. If you look at the following picture [image]. You will see pin #4 labeled in the third row of pins across the top. It is a little hard to be sure from the pic but it looks like it is connected to GPIO4.

Comment: Ah, I see.. Which leads to Pin #7 on the GPIO Header. Which, in reality is GPIO04 or (GPIO_GCLK). Thanks for clearing this up! I was seriously confused!